# Can I disable gh-pages hosting for my forked repo?

Tags: github, github-pages

I've forked a repo that has `gh-pages` set as it's default branch. They're hosting it on a custom domain, so there is a custom `CNAME` file.

I'm getting emails from Github with the following:

> The page build completed successfully, but returned the following warning:
>
> CNAME already taken: styleguides.io

I don't need to host the site myself, the fork is just for making contribs back. I'm just looking for a way to disable gh-pages hosting for my fork, so I don't get these errors/emails anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest renaming the "branch" in your fork to something other than gh-pages, that should prevent it from triggering builds, but will still allow you to pull request to the gh-pages on the upstream parent.

Comment: I guess this is the best answer. You should consider this as the official answer.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the **gh-pages** branch on that forked repo. Then remove the `CNAME` file. That should fix this problem.

You can get those emails because your forked repo tried to send the GitHub server the same `CNAME` settings as another project. (In your case, the upstream repo you forked from.)

Comment: That indeed seems a quick fix, but not a solution. It makes it difficult to pull in new changes from upstream, and to rebase or merge your own work, or create new branches for future pull requests. Does anybody have a better solution?

Comment: Do you need the gh-pages branch? I'd suggest to remove it, if you won't be using it. Pull the changes just for the master branch or others and forget about the gh-pages.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you were actually needing that branch to make contributions. @dragon788 have gave you the best answer. Please check that. gh-pages must be present just on the final repo.