# How to prevent a (CNAME) file from ever being forked

Tags: github

I understand the problem: two repos having CNAME files with the same URL can cause a collision (see [Can I disable gh-pages hosting for my forked repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302712/can-i-disable-gh-pages-hosting-for-my-forked-repo)).

So, if my (public) gh-pages repo has a CNAME file, how can I prevent it ever being included as part of the forked repo (and thus causing a collision)?

I've played around with a few settings. (Please correct me if I'm wrong on any of these, but) this is what I found:

1. Adding "CNAME" to the .gitignore file: shares the list of files that shouldn't be included in the remote repo. It does not prevent the file from being forked in the first place.
2. Adding "CNAME" to the .git/info/excludes file: is a local setting that prevents the file from being added to the remote repo. But the CNAME file needs to be on the remote repo.
3. Adding the path to the .gitignore file, as in:

   [core]
         excludesfile = file-to-exclude.txt

is also a local setting (dependent on a global .gitignore file). And this doesn't prevent the forking.

(As a workaround, the file could be deleted on the forked repo, but that requires special knowledge on the part of the forker.)

So, is there a way to prevent the CNAME file from ever being in the fork, in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to prevent the CNAME file from ever being in the fork, in the first place?

No.

Git's ignore system prevents files from being tracked, which would cause the `CNAME` file not to be included in the parent repository in the first place. There is no mechanism to include a file in a Git repository but prevent it from being included in a clone (which is what "forks" really are).

Users who fork your repository could remove the `gh-pages` branch from their forks entirely after forking, or remove the `CNAME` file from the `gh-pages` branch as suggested in the question you linked.

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned above, any forker unwittingly can cause a collision. The only way to prevent this, then, is by making that repo private. A private repo is the only reliable way to use CNAME files in gh-pages? Thanks!